# trim hex from end of string

Tags: c#, string, hex, trim

I have a byte array that's been initialized with 0xFF in each byte:

```
for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
{
    buffer[i] = 0xFF;
}
```

Once this byte array has been filled with valid data, I need to extract an ASCII string that's stored at offset 192 and may be up to 32 characters in length.  I'm doing this like so:

```
ASCIIEncoding enc = new ASCIIEncoding();
stringToRead = enc.GetString(buffer, 192, 32);
```

This works but I need to strip off the trailing bytes that contain 0xFF to avoid the string looking something like "John Smith??????????????????????".  Is there a function in .NET that provides this ability?  Something like the String.TrimEnd() function perhaps or am I looking at a regex to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest just finding out how long the string will *really* be:

```
int firstFF = Array.IndexOf(buffer, (byte) 0xff, 192);
if (firstFF == -1)
{
    firstFF = buffer.Length;
}
stringToRead = Encoding.ASCII(buffer, 192, firstFF - 192);
```

I would *not* try to give `Encoding.ASCII` bytes which aren't valid ASCII-encoded text. I don't know *offhand* what it would do with them - I suspect it would convert them to `?` to show the error (as suggested by your existing output), but then you wouldn't be able to tell the difference between that and *real* question marks. For example:

```
byte[] data = { 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0xff, 0xff };
string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
Console.WriteLine(text.Contains((char) 0xff)); // False
Console.WriteLine(text.TrimEnd((char) 0xff).Length); // Still 5...
```

Now you *could* create an encoding which used some non-ASCII replacement character... but that's a lot of hassle when you can just find where the *binary* data stops being valid.

Comment: While I'd generally agree with you, there are cases in dealing with serial data where doing this kind of seek is a reasonable approach, since it is not known how many bytes have been read into the buffer.

Comment: @codekaizen: Where did I say seeking is unreasonable? I said not to do it *after* decoding from binary to text, as it won't do what you want...

Comment: Thanks Jon (and everyone else).  This solution works very well for me!

Answer (score 2):

```
var s = "Whatever" + new String((Char)0xFF, 32);
var trimmed = s.TrimEnd((Char)0xFF);
```

Alternatively, you can scan the string for the first index of the character, then take the substring:

```
var index = s.IndexOf((Char)0xFF);
var trimmed = s.Substring(0, index);
```

Comment: not sure, but this might fail because the 0xFF has been ASCII and is now encoded as UTF-16.

Comment: This *won't* work if the byte array contains a bunch of invalid ASCII characters - because they won't end up as Unicode U+00FF, they'll end up as '?'. Just because it works with a hand-crafted string doesn't mean that it will work with the original byte array.